# Why did my Ubuntu install foobar?

Tags: 14.04, startup

Everything was working fine and then I went to boot and would only get a blank/black screen. After a while if I would push enter then the shutdown cycle would start. I even tried typing in my password + enter thinking that might work but with no success.

So I decided to reinstall over the top of my existing system and here is where I'm at now:

[image]

What's going on here? how do I get this to stop showing up?

Comment: Looks like there was an issue with one of your partitions. Click M for manual and paste the contents of `blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`
You will more than likely need to run a `fsck` on the damaged partition.
You could also try sudo update-grub to see if grub can clean up the pieces.

Comment: Can you please describe what *reinstall over the top of my existing system* entailed? The error message complains about EFI which is suspicious.

Comment: I installed using "other" so that my existing user files aren't deleted.